# python Regular expression

Tags: python, regex, function

```
file = open("demo.txt","r")
text = file.read()

def find(info):
    match = re.findall(r"info+\w+\d+",text)
    if match:
        print(match)
    else:
        print("Not found!")
```

my question is, how to apply 'info' in the function,
have no idea how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you be a lot more clear? The function takes the argument `info` but you are giving the the `findall` function the argument `text`...

Comment: sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
file = open("demo.txt","r")
text = file.read()

def find(info,text):
    match = re.findall(info + "+\w+\d+",text)
    if match:
        print(match)
    else:
        print("Not found!")

# This is how you call the function
find("whatever info is supposed to be",text)
```

Comment: This still uses the global variable `text` in `re.findall` rather than the function argument `info`

Comment: @isosceleswheel: Well spotted - Code adjusted accordingly

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Review your Python syntax a bit.

```
# beware "file" is a python keyword so you might want to use a different name
file = open("demo.txt","r")
# your text is called "text" so that is the argument to use in the function call
text = file.read()

# define the function: 

def find(info):
    # your variable is called "info" in the function so call findall on "info"
    match = re.findall(r"info+\w+\d+",info)
    if match:
        print(match)
    else:
        print("Not found!")

# call the function on "text" since that is the name of the local variable you created with file.read()::
find(text)
```